# ASP.NET MVC3: Is it possible to make @Html.TextBoxFor text to be hidden

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, textbox, passwords

Would it be possible to make `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => EmployeeID)`, text in the view to be hidden, when typed in. The same functionality as `@Html.PasswordFor`. There are reasons why I cannot use PasswordFor.

I want the same functionality from my previous post.
[ASP.NET MVC3 HtmlPasswordFor how to make it not reset after post methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179440/asp-net-mvc3-htmlpasswordfor-how-to-make-it-not-reset-after-post-methods)

EDIT

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179440/asp-net-mvc3-htmlpasswordfor-how-to-make-it-not-reset-after-post-methods

My previous post answered it using password for. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to hide the values typed in to be hidden, other than using a password type (which doesn't so much hide them as obscure them).  You could set the text color to the same as the background color, but all someone has to do is copy and paste the text out of it.  Also, if the textbox is populated on get or post, then they can view source and see the values.

EDIT:

The reason PasswordFor doesn't populate the the textbox on post is because it's a security vulnerability.  All someone has to do is view source and they can see what's in it.

If you understand this, and are ok with that.  Then you can simply use a standard input password box.

```
<input type="password" id="secrets" name="secrets" value="@Model.secrets" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:   `@Html.HiddenFor(m => EmployeeID)` this is what will make it.

Or, if you want just the text in the input to be hidden - set the text color to be same as the input color.

Good Luck

Comment: Sorry my question must have been sort of been confusing. I don't want the whole textbox to be hidden. I want to still be able to type in values into the textbox, but I want the values typed in the textbox to be hidden. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Austin Truong hmmm...I realy don't think there is such a thing..but personally I would set the same color of the input to the text.. hope I helped:)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the @value to the Model.PasswordFiels like in the example:

`@Html.PasswordFor(c => c.CodePassword, new { @class = "text", @value=Model==null?"":Model.CodePassword})`